# Calculate Laplace transformation of the product

Tags: laplace-transform

Laplace transformation of the derivative of the product equals?

$$L\left(\frac{d(f_1(y)f_2(y))}{dy}\right) = sf_1(s)f_2(s) - f_1(0)f_2(0) ?$$

I have meant not the convolution of the functions under the derivative operator, rather the derivative of their product.
Thank you.

Comment: I've edited your post to hopefully make the formatting a bit cleaner; please verify that it says what you've intended.

Comment: Where did you find this? It should be $ s\mathcal{L}(f_1f_2)-f_1(0)f_2(0) $.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(y)=f_1(y) f_2(y)$, then we have

> $$ \mathcal{L}(g') = sG(s)-g(0), $$

where

> $$ G(s)=\mathcal{L}\left\{ f_1 f_2\right\}(s). $$

**Added** On the other hand, the Laplace of the convolution is

> $$ \mathcal{L}\left\{ f_1*f_2 \right\}=\mathcal{L} \left\{ f_1\right\} \mathcal{L} \left\{ f_2\right\} .$$

There are not the same.

Comment: yes, thank you.  I wander how should look like the Laplace transform of a product via the convolution of the Laplace transforms of the multiplicands?

Comment: @user116425: It is two different things. the Laplace of the convolution is $ \mathcal{L}\left\{ f_1*f_2 \right\}=\mathcal{L} \left\{ f_1\right\} \mathcal{L} \left\{ f_2\right\} $.

Answer (score 0):

Let $  \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s)=F(s)$ and $  \mathcal{L}\{g(t)\}(s)=G(s)$

So, we have:

$ \mathcal{L}\left\{ f(t)g(t) \right\}(s)= \frac{1}{2i\pi}   \lim_{T \to \infty} \int\limits_{Re(w)-iT}^{Re(w)+iT} F(w)G(s-w)\,\mathrm dw, $

Or: you can take the Laplace Transform as a particular case of Fourier Transform.

---

For more information see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform